# Removing a style when two classes are both equal to the other. (CSS, HTML, JS)

Tags: javascript

I'm working on something that wants me to do this:

> "If both are equal to rangeOne.value remove the hidden class from finishPuzzleOne."

This is what I tried doing.

```
if (rangeThree.value + rangeTwo.value == rangeOne.value) {
    finishPuzzleOne.classList.remove('hidden');`
```

This was meant to produce a button, with id of "finishPuzzleOne" and class 'hidden'. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(rangeThree.value==rangeTwo.value&&rangeTwo.value==rangeOne.value){
  finishPuzzleOne.classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

Does that solve it?

Comment: yea so the `&&` was the AND operator, the `||` is the OR operator.. i suggest you research `javascript operators` for future occasion